# Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet in azure bicep

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

I am getting this weird error when trying to enable logging using azure bicep. The workspace is already created, and I am trying to retrieve the ID and apply in different Resources. I have used module to get ID and still the same error.

```
resource log_analytics_name 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2022-10-01' = {
  name: log_analytics_name_var
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'PerGB2018'
    }
    retentionInDays: 30
    features: {
      enableLogAccessUsingOnlyResourcePermissions: true
    }
    workspaceCapping: {
      dailyQuotaGb: -1
    }
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
  }
}
 
resource diagnosticSlogging 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: definition_name
  name: 'WAF_logs_to_storage'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: '/subscriptions/${toLower(subscription().subscriptionId)}/resourceGroups/${toLower(resourceGroup().name)}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/${log_analytics_name_var}'
    logs: [
      {
        category: null
        categoryGroup: 'allLogs'
        enabled: true
        retentionPolicy: {
          enabled: true
          days: 90
        }
      }
    ]
    metrics: [
      {
       category: 'AllMetrics'
       enabled: true
        retentionPolicy: {
          days: 0
          enabled: false
        }
        timeGrain: null
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [
    log_analytics_name
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you try workspaceId: log_analytics_name.id

Comment: what s the error ?

Comment: The same code is being used to enable key vault logging and now I am enabling logging in Front door, but still used the same log analytic workspace. We recently converted all our arm template code into bicep.

Comment: That error usually means there's a syntax error in the file somewhere - the cmdlet is trying to parse the template to see what parameters it contains.  A few things you can try 1) run `bicep build` on the file to see if it builds 2) remove things from the file until the error goes away 3) post the entire file and we can take a look...